# Sum of node count in each row

Tags: views

I have a view that uses aggregation to count the number of nodes of a color type. For example, there are 10 red nodes, 10 green nodes, and 20 blue nodes. For each color, I would like the number of nodes of that color and the total number of nodes, to show on each row.

| Color | Count | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 10 | 40 |
| Green | 10 | 40 |
| Blue | 20 | 40 |

Ultimately, I do want to calculate the percentage in each row as well.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A no-custom-code solution could be something like this (not the most performant way though but you could perhaps do something with views caching).

**Explanation:**
Create one view for the total count that with the use of aggregration and a content type filter returns the total number of nodes (the Total column)
In another **Taxonomy Terms view** you attach the total count view by adding a **Global: View** field that is provided by the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module

**Steps**
 - Create a content type e.g. "*Colornode*"
 - Create a taxonomy vocabulary called "*Colors*"
 - Add three terms *Blue*,*Green* and *Red*
 - Add a term reference field and select Colors as the vocabulary
 - Install and enable the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)  module

Then import these two views in this order:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'nodecounts';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Node counts';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Node counts';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['inline'] = array(
  'type_1' => 'type_1',
  'type' => 'type',
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['separator'] = ': ';
/* Field: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['id'] = 'type_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type_1']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Field: COUNT(Content: Type) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['separator'] = '';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'colornode' => 'colornode',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
```

And the second one:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'colorterms';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Color terms';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Color terms';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '100';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content using Color */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_color_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_color_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_color_node']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_color_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_color_node';
/* Relationship: Content: Color (field_color) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_color_tid']['id'] = 'field_color_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_color_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_color';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_color_tid']['field'] = 'field_color_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_color_tid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_color_node';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Field: COUNT(Content: Color) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['id'] = 'field_color';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['table'] = 'field_data_field_color';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['field'] = 'field_color';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_color_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['label'] = 'Count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_color']['separator'] = ', ';
/* Field: Global: View */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['id'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['field'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['label'] = 'Total';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['view'] = 'nodecounts';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view']['display'] = 'block';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'colors' => 'colors',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_color_node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'colornode' => 'colornode',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'color-terms';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Color terms';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'color-terms';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Color terms';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
```

Result
[image]